# Many application crashes 'Loki' some system hangs

Tags: release-loki, pantheon, crash

Hi installation to SSD without swap (none recommended for SSD life).
swapon -s returns null, and i've set swap in fstab thus:
UUID=******* swap swap sw, noauto 0 0
Im a Linux user for years BUT on this install I get many app crashes. (Pantheon is in SSD directory: /etc/profile.d/pantheon-filechooser-module.sh)
Instantiating app via terminal feedback usually includes

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
```

If I try to load LibreOffice these are the last lines after above:

```
(soffice:16014): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large
```

This continues with many other apps and it would be great if anyone could provide any advice as my mate Google has none.

To summaries I cannot use Libreoffice/Chrome or several other apps installed using Elementary Appcenter which is a very nice substitute for synaptic thank you. One thing I notice is if there is a show in tray option, and disable it some apps will not crash any more.

Loki is Lovely apart from this. I feel that due to the uniqueness of my issues its simply a hardware issue but cant figure what. Any help appreciated.

*Ill add a few more load-ups via terminal:*

```
:~$ skrooge
WARNING: QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
WARNING: QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

(skrooge:2921): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(skrooge:2921): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(skrooge:2921): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(skrooge:2921): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

*the following crash:*
alistair@alistair-X202EP:~$ libreoffice
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

(soffice:3011): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(soffice:3011): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(soffice:3011): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(soffice:3011): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(soffice:3011): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large

(soffice:3011): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large
intel_do_flush_locked failed: Bad address
```

Answer (score 1):

The most recent system update as of mid July 2017 in appcenter seems to partially fix the application problems; as I suspected the gtk-warning/error have now been removed.
This allowed me to open apps which previously crashed such as Libreoffice and Skrooge. However, system slowdowns and lockups persisted. If you read the issues in my OP you would see I have SSD only (with limited RAM of 2Gb). It is not recommended for SSD to use swapfile but if you are suffering from similar problems reported here try this in terminal (or use synaptic): `sudo apt-get install swapspace`
[swapspace info](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/01/automatic-virtual-swap-space-creator-ubuntu-linux/)
To improve further if you have limited RAM and using SSD only, I also recommend making a ZRAM script which reduces write to swapspace files considerably, and doesn't seem to slow the system.
[ZRAM script wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/ZRam)